# How to know LayoutParams of View before measurement?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have custom view with child items, which are configureable via xml. However they are can be configurable in runtime via something like a Configuration class. After that I just notify parent view about changes and all is ok.
BTW. My question in fact touches measurement: I can change child items size in runtime, but for the first launch I want to set to all of them size (width and height) accordingly to layout params defined in xml.

Maybe some code will add more clarification to you.

```
protected int getItemWidth() {
    if (cell != null) {
        int width = cell.getWidth();
        return width == 0 ? <layout_width_defined_in_xml> : ScreenUtils.convertToDp(context, width);
    } else {
        return canvasWidth;
    }
}
```

So, I want to know. Is possible to get layout params before measurement? And how to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size defined in XML isn't always the right size the view should have when it's actually laid out. For example, a child of a `LinearLayout` may have `android:layout_width="0"`, but might have nonzero width because of `android:layout_weight`. (There are other examples as well with other kinds of layouts.) Additionally, the values `match_parent` and `wrap_content` map to negative integer values in java code, which I don't think is helpful to you here.

If your custom view is interested in measuring and positioning child views, you should be overriding `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()`. If you aren't doing that or if you don't need to do that, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` will tell you a view's actual size, and `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` will tell you the measured size (which can differ from the actual size). THe only caveat is that you have to wait for the first measure/layout before calling those 4 methods because otherwise those methods all return zero.

If you do want to inspect the layout parameters of a view, you can do

```
LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
int width = params.width;
int height = params.height;
```

As noted, either or both of those may be negative. You can compare them to `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` and `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` to check for these cases, but again I'm not sure this is helpful to you if you aren't implementing `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()`.

Comment: Actually you are almost correct and I really want to avoid to write my own answer for this. So I would to ask you to simplify your answer :)
The simple answer for `Is possible to get layout params before measurement?` **- YES**, How? Via `getLayoutParams()` method. He always returns by default layout params that was defined in xml.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov My answer contains exactly that, but has further explanation for why this might not be a good thing to do (both for you and for anyone else who reads this answer). I don't see any reason that you would have to write another answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in callback `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`. You can get view dimensions here and set size other views with these dimensions.